# Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

on running following command

```
pm> Update-Database
```

getting following error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception.
>   --->  System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

Comment: May be that can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572705/what-causes-a-typeloadexception-on-migrate-exe-for-ef6

Comment: Do all projects in your solution refer to the same Entity Framework version? Did you do a clean and full rebuild? What caused this error, did it work before and did you change anything?

Answer (score 5):

Your EF version and Project Version is not Equal.
your Entity Framework is ver 6 of .Net 4 but your project use .net 4.5
Project by .net version 4.5 must use EF for .Net4.5

Comment: i found no issue in the app.config, but this was the solution:
- Uninstall entity framework
- Reinstall entity framework

Comment: Actually, even if you use a newer version of ef like 6.1.3 like I am using, it will still say version 6.0.0.0 in the error message.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (EF 6.1.3 & net462) and I tried all the answers, but nothing fixed the problem. When I eventually switched to Release configuration, it worked liek a charm.

Not sure what's wrong with Debug, since they are almost identically, except for debug trace etc.

Hope this helps other people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had a similar problem.  After a long time I found that one project referenced Entity Framework version 6.1.1 and in another project version 6.1.3 is referenced in same solution. I removed 6.1.3 from the package manager console. Problem is finally solved.

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

Not the ideal solution, but I switched back to [Entity Framework 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0) and the problem went away. Found this useful [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8b52c57-e3b8-466f-aca2-9d823f37226e/method-getxxx-from-assembly-yyyy-does-not-have-an-implementation?forum=csharpgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After spending some hours to fix this. What fixed the problem was: I closed the project, created a new one with the same name, copied my folders and classes I created to the new project and downloaded the packages I needed through nuget. Then Add-Migration ...... everything went well afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I run other project which has 6.1.3 version. then my project does not work. so I updated entity_framework same version with the other project. restarted project, run the enable-migrations command. it worked!!

happy coding