# Entity Framework not working after trying to update project to v6 and retarget to .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a project that I built in VS 2010 targeting .Net 4.0. I am trying to pick up work on this project using VS 2015 -- I targeted .Net 4.5 and uninstalled/reinstalled all my packages. I am now getting the following error when trying to run `update-database`:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

I have removed the references to the EntityFramework dll's and added references to the ones in the net45 folder. I have uninstalled and reinstalled EF multiple times. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but not sure what else to check. All of the answers I've seen on this error seem to indicate some version conflict between the EF version I have installed and some reference in my code, but I'm not sure where else to check. Any ideas?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513621/entity-framework-code-first-migrations

Comment: do you have multiple projects or what?

Comment: I don't have multiple projects, this is the only one. And o have read the linked question, but it just says to uninstall/reinstall EF...

Comment: can you check the version of `EF assembly` manually on the solution explorer ? check whether is the correct or not ?

Comment: @Sampath -- For both EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer I show a version of 6.0.0.0 and a runtime version of 4.0.30319 (is that correct for 4.5??).