# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.String)'.

Line 153:            {
Line 154:                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
Line 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 157:                {

Source File: g:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication17\WebApplication17\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 155
```

I am faced with the error message when starting a new MVC project from Visual Studio 2013. I have the latest updates for VS (Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4) - .NET Version 4.5.5.1650.

I believe this has something to do with Entity Framework version 6.1.3.30610.0. I've tried updating it thru Nuget. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it and still no luck.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: have you prib dowload the ef6 dll and add the references to the ddl? this error is that the ef isnt working !

Comment: Do you mean manually download EF dll and add the reference? Not thru Nuget? Thanks.

Comment: EF is included with the startup MVC project.

Comment: try with this hiperlink https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxIKiOSA8XHqeXZIbnJGWHpxcWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using the MVC startup with the default Individual User Account authentication.

Comment: create your project , but first, you should install the version for vs2013 of mvc, install and proib !

Comment: Thanks for the files, but when I add the references - I receive this error now: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

Comment: Check the version of framework if is 4.0, if isnt, you should chang e the version per 4.0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572705/what-causes-a-typeloadexception-on-migrate-exe-for-ef6

Comment: I was trying to do this with .NET Framework 4.5.1. I will change it to .NET 4.0 and try again.

Comment: Creating a new project in .net 4, EF works fine. It's when I use .net 4.5.1 is where I have issues with.

Comment: Not for .NET 4.5.1 which is the framework I'm trying to use.

Comment: I believe theres a bug in EF 6.1.2. I rolled EF back to 6.1.0 and it worked fine. update-package entityframework -version 6.1.0

Comment: ok, i hope you can resolve it!