# Upgrading solution from EF4 to EF6 strange error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am upgrading my solution to use EF6 about 5 projects in the solution use Entity Framework.

When I run the web application I get the following error

> Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

I can't seem to find a solution online, and from what I can see all the different projects are pointing to the same EF Version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a TypeLoadException on Migrate.exe for EF6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572705/what-causes-a-typeloadexception-on-migrate-exe-for-ef6)

Comment: Im not using any migrations, this is just loading the application with an existing database.

Comment: @Plexis, I agree completely it's not a dup -- any future person who experienced the problem you're experiencing would find a signpost to that question utterly baffling.  That being said, the error reported in that question seems to be the same, so you may want to see if you can adapt the answer there for your purposes.